# Immutable covariant collection with uniqueness

Tags: scala

I would like an immutable collection that has the properties of a) covariance and b) uniqueness. My collection size will never be large, and I am less concerned about fast `contains`.

Currently I am simply using my own `uniquePrepend` extension method on `List`, but this is rather unsatisfactory because uniqueness is not internally enforced.

Does anyone know of a collection out there that satisfies (a) and (b)? If not, is there a more elegant solution to this than my extension method? Thanks

Comment: [This thread](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/2685.html) might be of interest, which contains various arguments about the type parameter's contravariant position in `contains` and `add`, but I get the impression a covariant Set isn't impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could never understand why they didn't want a `Set` to be covariant. All you need to do is make it `Any => Boolean` rather than `A => Boolean`. 
You can implement it yourself as a wrapper around `Set[Any]`, it won't be pretty, but will do what you want ...

Comment: That did it... it sure isn't pretty, but it did it

Comment: Because setOfInts.contains("string") is usually a programmer error and it would be nice to catch it at compile time.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon What about `listOfInts.contains("string")`. Is that less "nice to catch"? Why?

Comment: @Dima Because lists are less commonly used for containment checking, so covariance was more of a priority than a safe contains. Language design is full of compromises.

Comment: I know. I just think that this particular compromise is wrong. It's inconvenient, and inconsistent with the rest of the library. Not just with `listOfInts.contains("string")` but also with `"foo" == 25`, or with `Set("foo") ++ Set(25)` ... etc.